# Symfony 2.1 bad credentials only when encoding the password

Tags: authentication, encoding, symfony, password-protection

Here is my code for adding admin user:

```
public function addAction(Request $request){
    $admin=new Admin();
    $form=$this->createForm(new AdminType(), $admin);
    if($request->getMethod()=='POST'){
        $form->bindRequest($request);
        if($form->isValid()){
            $factory = $this->get('security.encoder_factory');
            $encoder = $factory->getEncoder($admin);
            $password = $encoder->encodePassword($admin->getPassword(), $admin->getSalt());
            $admin->setPassword($password);

            $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
            $em->persist($admin);
            $em->flush();
        }
    }
    return $this->render('PuzzleAdminBundle:Admin:add.html.twig', array(
        'form'=>$form->createView()
    ));
}
```

and here is my security.yml:

```
security:
encoders:
    Puzzle\AdminBundle\Entity\Admin: sha512
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

providers:
    chain_providers:
        chain:
            providers: [admin_db, in_memory]
    admin_db:
        entity: { class: Puzzle\AdminBundle\Entity\Admin, property: username }
    in_memory:
        memory:
            users:
                root: { password: 123456, roles: [ 'ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN' ] }
```

Everything is OK when i want to login on root, or when I set up entity encoder to plaintext. Why I always get bad credentials when I set up entity encoder to sha512?

Answer (score 8):

Check the field length in your database. If you were following "The Book" then likely your field will be set to `varchar(50)`. Base64-encoded SHA-512 will output an 88 character string. Adjust for this and you should be good to go.

Comment: You sir, are a gentleman and a scholar! I was following the book and assumed I did something wrong with the YML files... sigh.

Comment: OMG!!! Thank you so much! I just spent two hours changing everything and you saved me!

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the 'password' value defined would need to be the value post-encoding.  So the value it will be looking for when set up to use a sha512 encoder will be the sha512 hash of '123456' rather than the plain text password.

Take a look here:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#encoding-the-user-s-password . The paragraph after the first example in this section deals with this specifically.

Answer (score 1):

I had the problem indicated and in my case it was a pretty silly thing, the length of the field in the database too small